# Tensorflow ArgumentError: argument --model_dir: conflicting option string: --model_dir

Tags: machine-learning, python, tensorflow

I am trying to execute this Tensorflow tutorial https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.12/tensorflow/examples/learn/wide_n_deep_tutorial.py but I have the following error:

ArgumentError: argument --model_dir: conflicting option string: --model_dir

that appears in line:

flags.DEFINE_string("model_dir", "", "Base directory for output models.")

Do you know how I can solve it?

Thanks in advance,

Keira

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you linked is from version 0.12 but the current tensorflow version is 1.2. The example underwent a lot of changes from 0.12 to 1.0. Actually, the very line you are referencing is no longer there in the last version.

This way, it's possible that you are using a version of tensorflow that is no longer compatible with the APIs used by the example. Ensure that the version of tensorflow you are using is the same as the example.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the Tensorflow version and it worked. However, I have another error just after the printing of the accuracies, recalls, etc.: An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit. Do you know what can I do to print this error? Do you know what is the cause? Thank you.

Comment: Are you running it on IPython or any other similar environment ?

Comment: Yes, with Jupyter.

Comment: Then the cause is the final line in the example, which invokes `tf.app.run`. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39463046/674487), it passes the result of `main()` to `sys.exit()`. Jupyter does not like when you invoke `sys.exit()`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36944403/674487). You can modify the last line to do [the same](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9dc6c17797c065796603d9259b2aa57b3c07ff71/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py#L31-L48) without exiting. Or simply ignore the error.

Comment: Now the example of the tutorial works but when I try to use my data the following error message appears: Expected binary or unicode string in the line tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed). I tried to put information between ' because I thought the problem could be to have integers without quotes, but I have the same problem adding '. Thank you in advance.